# Копирование виджетов yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2, select2

Задача выполнятся в фреймворке yii2.

Задача следующая. Есть два виджета. Эти виджеты должны копироваться по кнопке "добавить".
Само "копирование" виджетов происходит. Однако(!) на "вновь появившихся" инпутах js не работает.

Вопрос как заставить работать js на всех инпутах которые добавляются по кнопке "добавить"?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click', '.add-product', function (){
      $(".product").clone().appendTo(".form-product-items");
   })
});
```

PHP код:

```
<section class="main-content form-product-items">
    <div class="container form-product-item">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php
                echo $form->field($model, 'category')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => [],
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Категория'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true,
                        'tags' => true
                    ],
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <?php
                echo $form->field($model, 'product')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => [],
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Продукт', 'multiple' => true],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'tags' => true
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <?= Html::button('Добавить', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block add-product w-100']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: После добавления новых элементов в DOM, нужно на них развесить все то что Вы вешаете на основные инпуты.

Comment: вы добавили код JS от копирования виджета, а какой именно JS код не работает?

Comment: Ваш вариант не работает потому, что все js-события виджетов при дублировании элементов нужно вешать по новой на каждый созданный вашим методом элемент. Вы можете использовать [MultipleInput](https://github.com/unclead/yii2-multiple-input), на мой взгляд так будет проще и быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно попробовать клонировать так:

```
$(".product").clone(true, true).appendTo(".form-product-items");
```

В таком случае будут копироваться и слушатели, которые стоят на элементе.

---

Если это не поможет, то придётся лезть в код виджета, смотреть, какие слушатели куда навешиваются и вручную добавлять слушателей на склонированные элементы

---

Ещё вариант - сходить в документацию к виджету и посмотреть, есть ли там строки про какую-нибудь "реинициализацию". Наверняка там есть доп. данные, как "запускать" новый виджет с новыми данными